# Barbeau's Polynomials: Quadratic Polynomials, 1.2.2

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> [image]

---

- I've verified $(a)$ by expanding the $RHS$.

---

- I've partially verified $(b)$ doing the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {p(t)}&\stackrel{?}{=}&{p(t)-p(r)}&\stackrel{?}{=}&{(t-r)(at+ar+b)} \\ 
  {p(t)}&\stackrel{?}{=}&{at^2+bt+c-ar^2-br-c}&\stackrel{?}{=}&{at^2+art+bt-art-ar^2-br} \\ 
  {p(t)}&\stackrel{?}{=}&{at^2+bt-ar^2-br}&\stackrel{done}{=}&{at^2+bt-ar^2-br} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Now I'm facing a problem: To prove that $p(t)=at^2+bt-ar^2-br$, I guess I need to do the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {p(t)}&=&{at^2+bt-ar^2-br} \\ 
  {at^2+bt+c}&=&{at^2+bt-ar^2-br} \\ 
  {c}&=&{-ar^2-br} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The problem is that I have no clue why $c=-ar^2-br$.

---

- For $(c)$ I've done the following:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {p(t)}&=&{(t-r)q(t)} \\ 
  {at^2+bt+c}&=&{(t-r)(gt+h)} \\ 
  {}&=&{gt^2+ht-gtr-rh} 
\end{eqnarray*}$$

If I assume that $at^2=gt^2, bt=ht$ and $c=-gtr-rh$, it's done. But I guess that to assume that $c=-gtr-rh$, I need to show that $c=-ar^2-br$ on $(b)$ and I'm still stuck at this.

Also, $q(t)$ must be linear because if it were of $\deg 0$, it wouldn't work because it couldn't have terms of $\deg 2$. And if it were of $\deg >1$, the multiplication by $t$ would generate a term with $\deg >2$. (Altough I'm not sure if this is enough to show it).

Answer (score 1):

Because $r$ is the zero of the polynomial, that means $p(r)=0$.

For b) Thus $p(t)=p(t)-p(r)=at^2+bt+c-ar^2-br-c=(t-r)(at+ar+b)$.

For c) Always $p(t)=(t-r)q(t)=0$ if and only if $t=r$ or $p(t)=p(r)$ which is the def. of the zero of the polynomial.